# Notepad++ Any Character

Tags: search, notepad++

Does anyone know how to search something like this in the search box of Notepad++ ?

ID. 213

Debt: 13 $

I want this to be searched  like :

"ID. (don'care for the number/any character),newline, Debt(don'care for the number/any character)"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turn on regular expression mode in Find, with "`. matches newline`" enabled:

Search for:

```
ID\.\s.*[\n]+Debt:\s.*$
```

Older versions of Notepad++ have difficulty matching multi-line regexes, be sure to have version 6+ Notepad++ for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
ID\..*?Debt:
```

Don't forget to enable `. matches newline`

**explanation:**

```
(?^:ID\..*?Debt:)
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:ID\..*?Debt:)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ID                       'ID'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character including \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Debt:                    'Debt:'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This does not explicitly match the newline, it would also match "ID. Debt:" on one line.